# Send data MainActivity to FragmentStateAdapter to Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I am developing an application on android and I encounter a problem.

The existing topics on StackoverFlow do not answer my problem, they are not under kotlin and do not go through 3 class

I would like to display data from an object (**Activity**). The problem is that it's object is in my MainActivity and I have to pass it through several kotlin classes (MainActivity -> AdapterToto -> UnityInfoFragment.

MainActivity.kt :

```
    val pager = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager2)
    val tab1 = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayoutDetail)
    pager.adapter = AdapterToto(supportFragmentManager,lifecycle, Activity())


    TabLayoutMediator(tab1, pager){ tab, positon ->
        tab.text = tabTitle[positon]
    }.attach()
```

AdapterToto.kt :

```
class AdapterToto(fragmentManager: FragmentManager,lifecycle: Lifecycle, private val myData : Activity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager,lifecycle){
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 4
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {



    when(position){
        0 -> return ActivityInfoFragment()
        1 -> {
            return UnityInfoFragment(myData)
        }
        2 -> return StatistiqueFragment()
        3 -> return StatistiqueFragment()
        else -> return ActivityInfoFragment()
    }
}
```

}

UnityInfoFragment :

```
class UnityInfoFragment(private val myData: Activity) : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    Log.e("TOTO",myData.toString())

    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unity_info, container, false)
}
```

}

Once the data arrives in the fragment, how can I retrieve the textfield and display it dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: The existing topics on StackoverFlow do not answer my problem, they are not under kotlin and do not go through 3 class